# Pass selected index of object that resides outside of a v-for loop in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I'm creating a simple shopping cart in Vue 3 for learning purposes.

So far, I've set up everything from the `products` object to the `addToCart()` functionality, and everything works within a `v-for` loop.

The problem is I need to display the product's title within an alert that resides outside the `v-for` loop and I have no idea how to do that in Vue.

I tried `emit` and `provide` but it's not working. I can send the entire object to the child component `Alert.vue` via `provide` but that's not helpful as I only need to get the current index of the selected product to be able to fetch its title.

You can check a demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-cart-54ioqt?file=/src/App.vue

Try adding a product to the cart twice and check the Alert. At the moment it's displaying the entire cart object but I only need to fetch the `title` of the product so that the alert would say `You have already added {product.title} to your cart`

App.vue

```
export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
        CartAlert
    },
    data() {
        return {
            products: [
                {id: 1, title: 'Samsung A70', price: 50},
                {id: 2, title: 'Kindle Reader', price: 50},
                {id: 3, title: 'Meta Quest 2', price: 100},
                {id: 4, title: 'LG LED 43" TV', price: 200},
            ],
            discountInput: '',
            discountValid: false,
            cart: [],
            total: '',
            alreadyAddedToCart: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addToCart(index) {
            if (this.cart.includes(this.products[index])) {
                this.alreadyAddedToCart = true
            } else {
                this.cart.push(this.products[index])
            }
        },
    },
    provide() {
        return {
            cart: this.cart
        }
    }
}
```

`Alert.vue` (child component)

```
<template>
    <div id="alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        You have already added this {{ cart }} to your cart.
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"
                @click="$emit('dismissAlert')"></button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CartAlert",
    props: ['product'],
    inject: ['cart'],
    mounted() {
        console.log()
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show your prop `product` in Cart component:

```
You have already added this {{ product }} to your cart.
```

In app add `item` to data function:

```
item: null
```

in method add title to that data property:

```
this.item = this.products[index].title
this.alreadyAddedToCart = true;
```

in template bind your property to `item`:

```
:product="item"
```

[your demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-cart-forked-18npvf)

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!